# How to cancel stop function in react native voice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, voice-recognition

I have got a project in react native, the main idea is - speech to text from user. I have one problem: If the user makes a short pause, then the translation of speech into text is allowed. How can i pass this? Code below

```
useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
    return () => {-
      Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
      
    }
  }, []);

  const startSpeechToText = async () => {
    await Voice.start("en-US");
  };


  const stopSpeechToText = async () => {
    await Voice.stop();
    setStarted(false);

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can listen to events like `onSpeechEnd` or `onSpeechPartialResults` and if it happens start recognition again. But in this case, you need the stop button or any way to stop recognition.

Also you can check this issue it is related to your question https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice/issues/107

Answer (score -1):

Below code snippet may help you in that

```
      useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
          Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStartHandler;
          Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEndHandler;
          Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResultsHandler;
          return () => {
            Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
          };
        }, []),
      );


 const onSpeechEndHandler = (e) => {
    updateState({
      isVoiceRecord: false,
    });
  };

  const onSpeechResultsHandler = (e) => {
    let text = e.value[0];
   
    _onVoiceStop();
  };

  const _onVoiceListen = async () => {
    const langType = languages?.primary_language?.sort_code;
    updateState({
      isVoiceRecord: true,
    });
    try {
      await Voice.start(langType);
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  const _onVoiceStop = async () => {
    updateState({
      isVoiceRecord: false,
    });
    try {
      await Voice.stop();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error raised', error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Adding an explanation as to how your snippet behaves and some of the methods works might be helpful in improving this answer